# How to modify a page content before applying filters in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I need to change a page content source, and get it not from DB, but from an external file.
I've decided add a custom field 'staticfile' to page I want to change source. Then I wrote mini-plugin and added there filter "the_content":

```
add_filter('the_content', 'static_content');
function static_content($content) {
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom();
    $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['staticfile'];
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    foreach ($my_custom_field as $value) {
        if ($value) {
            $file = file_get_contents($upload_dir['basedir'] . '/staticpages/' . $value);
            return $file;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

It works fine excepting one thing. The html-code I get on ouput is not filtered. For example, shortcodes added with another plugins doesn't work. I tried to write:

```
return apply_filters('the_content', $file);
```

But it breaks all output (probably it loops the code).
Is there a way to change source of page with applying filters?

Comment: I was wrong. Shortcodes work good excepting some plugin which uses no

Comment: I was wrong. Shortcodes work, excepting some old plugin which uses regex to replace content (probably it is not good method). Anyway it would be informative for me to know how can I set a page content, and then let's every plugin modify it. Maybe I don't understand enough how filters work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to apply a priority parameter...
add_filter('the_content', 'static_content', 20); 
default for plugins is 10, so 20 means it runs lower priority. Try and see what to set it to, as the higher it is set to, then all plugins can modify it before you do work on it with your filter.
Think that is what you want.